# ASP.NET MVC IIS show network folder images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2008

I stay to shift my ASP.NET MVC website from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2016. Everything works fine, but I am not more able to show on webpage the images take from a network folder. To do it I have this part of controller that I call in the view:

```
    public ActionResult GetImg(string imagePath)
    {

        if (imagePath != null)
        {
            var path = $@"\\server\immagini\" + imagePath;
            try
            {
                var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                return File(bytes, "image/png");
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

I think it's a problem of permission, but are days that I compare the old server with the new, and all seems ok. Please someone cane help me?

Other info:

- From the new server I can access to the Shared folder
- Everything works fine in the old server

Comment: do you get any exception?, if yes then please share

Comment: No, Only the image error with "X", and I have tried to take off the try catch method, but no error it's given.

Comment: can you have some thing log on catch part so that you can get some exception

Comment: "I can access to the Shared folder" is useless. A web application uses the application pool identity to connect to that folder and it can be blocked.

Comment: I have the error:

Comment: System.IO.IOException: This specified server cannot perform the request operation.